# Not receiving droid texts on iphone

Tags: iphone, messages

I gave my granddaughter my samsung android phone when her iphone got broken. I now have an iphone. I have to send her texts using SMS (turned it on in settings) but when she answers I do not receive her replies on my iphone 5.   I've noticed my messages to other iphone users are not always iMessages anymore.  Frustrated with not being able to communicate with granddaughter.  Does it have anything to do with the droid was my phone before and used same number?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to do with your Number, it's a known Bug which happens to all iPhone Android switchers.

It has to do with the way Apple has made its iMessage service.

Thanks to an ongoing issue with the way Apple built its iMessage platform, users who switch away from an iPhone to an Android phone or any other cell phone are faced with a huge problem: once they bail on the iPhone, they often can’t receive text messages from contacts who are still using iPhones. This is because Apple’s system still sees them as iMessage users, and it tries to deliver messages sent using Apple’s Messages app as iMessages. To make matters even worse, the iPhone users who send those messages see their status as “delivered” even though they are not being received.

source http://bgr.com/2014/05/19/fix-imessage-iphone-bug-android-sms/.

i hope this will help you.

Comment: I believe this issue has been fixed(at least apple page suggests it has).  https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage/